# Find out whether a value is already present in the table or not

Tags: sql-server

i am having a column as LOCATION CODE in a table name as Company_Location
i want to find out that if a user enter the Location_Code it should not b already present in the table

Comment: how will i come to now tat the particular value is present or not

Comment: if the records exists you could put the selected records into a `temp table`

Comment: How will you behave differently based on whether the record exists or not?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
              SELECT NULL FROM Company_Location 
              WHERE Company_Location.[LOCATION CODE]=<Some value>)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Company_Location([LOCATION CODE])VALUES(<Some value>)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if exists (select Location_code from Company_Location where Location_code=<something>
begin
    ...Do something here!!
end
else 
PRINT 'records already exist'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
SELECT case when [LOCATION CODE] IS NOT NULL then 'Yes'  else 'No' end
FROM Company_Location
WHERE companyID = <value>
```